# Breaking apart a math equation string

Tags: java, regex

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\d.]|[\\d.]++)");
    String[] equation =  pattern.split("5+3--323");
    System.out.println(equation.length);
```

I'm trying to break apart numbers (could be groups) and nonnumbers, in this example i was hoping for a size 6 array:
5, +, 3, -, -, 323

how can I do this?

Comment: Aren't You trying to *parse* a math  *expression*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using matcher, as in example below. It returns exactly what you are after.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MathSplitTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[-+]");
        String string = "5+3--323";                 
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find())
            System.out.println("g0="+matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: have more than just - and +, but it was easy enough to add others and that gives me what i was looking for. thanks

Comment: @smerny Good to hear that this sorts out your problem. Yea I know,e.g. there are at least two more operations / *

Answer (score 2):

What about using a

```
new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.StringReader("5+3--323"));
```

instead?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers are comma separated then first tokenize the String;

```
tok = new StringTokenizer(string, ",");
```

then try to create a number from each token. If it is not a number then it's a symbol:

```
while (tok.hasMoreTokens()){
    String tok = tok.nextTok();
    try {
          new Integer(tok);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){

    }
}
```

If tok is not a number then a NumberFormatException is thrown.